# Ingresar datos usando Php a MySql en multiusuario

Tags: php, mysqli

Deseo Ingresar datos a `Mysql`, intenté usar la siguiente sentencia:

`$query="SELECT MAX(cod_unico)+1 ultimo FROM $tabla";`

pero este no me lo permite pues solo te trae el ultimo `id` pero al momento de ingresar puede haber duplicidad o errores por no permitir duplicidad.

Comment: Auto incrementales o transacciones.

Comment: El problema de la *duplicidad*  no queda solucionado con el hecho de tener una columna auto-incremental, sino que, cuando diseñas una tabla debes determinar cuál es la columna o combinación de columnas que deben ser **únicas** en cada fila de tabla, y en base esa(s) columna(s) declarar una restricción `UNIQUE` en la tabla. Por ejemplo en una tabla `persona` puedes determinar la unicidad mediante la columna `documento_identidad`, en una tabla `ciudad` la unicidad sería una combinación de las columnas `id_pais, id_region, id_provincia`. *Lo que evita la duplicidad es tener clara la unicidad*.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por tu tiempo y tu aporte que es excelente, lo que se desea y se hace enfasis es por ser multiusuario al llamar con un SELECT MAX() a los que estan ingresando datos se les refleja el mismo SELECT MAX() a todos por ende no permitirá trabajar en simultaneidad pues al primero que le de guardar listo ahí queda bien pero en microsegundo el 2 usuario intenta guardar y pues nada ahí está el error. Ya se ocupó ese SELECT MAX(id).

Comment: No me parece una buena idea lo que estás haciendo. Deberías declarar simplemente una columna `ID` que sea auto-incremental y dejar que el manejador controle eso, o sea, que aumente en `1` esa columna cada vez que un registro sea ingresado. El manejador controlará también que no se inserten registros duplicados si agregas la restricción `UNIQUE` a la tabla basándote en columnas como expliqué más arriba. Lo de `MAX(id)`, aparte de ser algo muy complicado en una BD con conexiones concurrentes, no evita registros duplicados por lo que expliqué antes.

Comment: @A.Cedano Como o de que manera sugieres que el usuario pueda ver el consecutivo que sigue o que correspondio en ese ingreso para asì basandose en ese ingreso unico se pueda seguir llevando un control basado en el codigo unico de ese ingreso. Teniendo en cuenta que no puede ser por numero de cedula.

Comment: @Rsistemas . Lo que comenta @A.Cedano es que dejes a la base de datos gestionar que los registros que insertas no estén duplicados, utilizando, como bien ha dicho, `UNIQUE` en los campos que deben ser únicos o `AUTO_INCREMENT` en la ID del registro. Si tu ID principal está definida con `AUTO_INCREMENT` la base de datos incrementará en uno su valor cada vez que insertes un registro, sin que tu tengas que especificar el valor de dicha ID.

Comment: Es que precisamente **el usuario no tiene por que ver o controlar los incrementos que se van haciendo en ese campo, esa es una tarea propia del manejador de base de datos**. Podríamos decir que lo que tú estás intentando hacer es *sustituir* al manejador, asumiendo una tarea que le corresponde a él y que él hace muy bien. Si tú asumes esa tarea te vas a complicar la vida y muy probablemente tendrás al final **datos erróneos**, dado que las conexiones concurrentes y los manejos que pueden hacer los usuarios son impredecibles. El problema de fondo, creo yo, es una confusión entre lo que debe...

Comment: ... ser una columna de identificación (llave primaria o primary key)  y una restricción de unicidad. En algunas tablas la llave primaria te sirve también como restricción de unicidad, pero en otras no. Imaginemos una tabla `persona` con dos filas: `1,José,Pérez,DNI123` y `2,José,Pérez,DNI123`. Tienes 2 `ID` distintos, pero es la misma persona, aquí no se aplica bien la restricción de unicidad, porque estás usando la primera columna para determinar los registros únicos, cuando deberías usar el `DNI` como restricción `UNIQUE`, o una combinación de `nombre,apellido` (menos probable).

Comment: @A.Cedano Listo atento tomando nota y aprendiendo, gracias por tu tiempo y dedicación. También gracias a los Administradores del sitio, es un muy excelente espacio.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es evitar que la ID de lo que estás insertando coincida con registros ya existentes, en la base de datos puedes usar `AUTO_INCREMENT` al definir tu tabla. Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  apellidos varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

De esta forma cuando insertes un nuevo registro solo debes especificar los campos `nombre` y `apellidos`, la ID se generaría automáticamente.

Si no puedes usar `AUTO_INCREMENT` tendrías que hacer un `SELECT MAX(id) FROM usuarios` para recuperar la `id` más grande que tengas y luego al hacer tu insert sumarle +1 al valor de dicha id. Aunque esta última opción no sería muy recomendable si muchos usuarios van a usar la aplicación de manera simultanea.

Comment: @Fermi  Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Veo eso como una soluciòn. Como le haria para hacer SELECT MAX(id) en PHP con Mysqli

Comment: Suponiendo que el campo de id se llama `cod_unico` y la tabla `tabla1`, solo tienes que pasar la consulta: `SELECT MAX(cod_unico) FROM tabla1;` y luego guardar el resultado en una variable para poder operar con esa ID.